# ViewingApplication with multiple viewers

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

This is more of a "best practices" question. It seems to me that a ViewingApplication as outline in the docs [here](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v6/tutorials/basic-application/) is directly tied to a div on the page. If that is true and I want to show both a 3d viewer and a 2d viewer, does that mean I need a seperate instance of the ViewingApplication for each div?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you will need as many separate containers for your Viewer instances, just so you can initialise them separately and Viewer won’t mind if these containers share the same parent - that’s so long as a Viewer can operate exclusively in a distinct, direct parent.

See [here](https://jsfiddle.net/dukedhx/5gx69s14/) for sample code accommodating multiple Viewers.

Alternatively if you are only after a quick fix to render several models in one div/canvas then the [SplitScreen Extension](https://autodeskviewer.com/viewers/latest/docs/Autodesk.Viewing.Extensions.SplitScreenExtension.html) probably fits the bill already:

```
var options = {
              viewports: [
                  function(id) { return id === 1; },
                  function(id) { return id !== 1; }
              ]
          };
viewer.loadExtension('Autodesk.SplitScreen', options);
```